# Simulating Gravity

Tags: simulation, calculus

Say I have an object next to me at my desk right now, and a java object in the program I am working on. If I were to drop the real object it would accelerate downwards at a speed of 9.81 m/s (ignoring wind resistance), thus the velocity would be 9.81 m/s/s and the overall position would be (-)9.81 m/s/s/s relative to where it started.

Now if I wrote a java program with my java object simulating this I would do it like such

```
public class HypotheticalObjectClass(){

    double position = 0, velocity = 0;

    tick(){
        velocity += 9.81;
        position += velocity;
    }

}
```

This program is accurate as long as I have it calling tick() once a second, but  if it's called multiple times a second the position skyrockets because of calculus or whatever... I intend to have this program tick multiple times a second, so how would I correct the calculation given only instantaneous values (such as velocity, position, rotation, etc...) and, if it is not possible, what system do I need to add to make it possible?

Sorry if this question was already addressed on this site, I have no idea how I'd find it, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the time difference between your `tick` calls, then you can scale acceleration and speed according to it.

```
public class HypotheticalObjectClass(){

    double position = 0, velocity = 0;

    public void tick(double dt) {
        velocity += 9.81 * dt;
        position += velocity * dt;
    }

}
```

If accelaration is in `units/s^2` and speed in `units/s` then `dt` is the time difference in **seconds** between function calls. So if you call it once a second, you should call it `obj.tick(1.0)`. However the best idea is to measure time between calls because, as you mentioned, the time difference is not always exactly the same.

Note that this method is quite inaccurate, however it is often good enough. For more information about physics simulation see: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/

Comment: I have a system for timing the calls elsewhere in the program, but the actual problem is much more confusing and difficult to see. If I were to have it tick 30 times a second, the first time it would add 1/30th of 9.81m/s to velocity, then add velocity to position, which is great. But the second time it's called it adds 1/30th of 9.81 to velocity, then 2/30ths to position, which then is already 3/30ths of 9.81, by the 8th tick it's already reached the proper position and will continue to drastically overshoot. It looses it's accuracy because of how fast the position accumulates.

Comment: Numerical integration is never 100% accurate. Read the given article if you need something better.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completely missed the last part.